# What software can I use for live streaming video overlay that accepts input?

Tags: web-apps, video, web-development, html, php

I am looking to build a site that allows for a live streaming video with an interactive overlay. The overlay should be able to allow questions to be asked to the audience. An example would be to ask the audience if they like cats, the question would display on their screen once the host asks the question and the audience would be able to click yes or no to submit their vote for the poll. The poll results would display the results on screen. Once the user votes, the question would disappear from their screen and only the poll results would remain. Rough sketch example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InqXq.jpg

I have looked at using ffmpeg and html5 as well as wowza. I am not familiar with wowza but have played around with ffmpeg and security camera feeds but by no means am I fluent in it.

I'm looking for insight on the use of the technologies I outlined as well as any other viable options.

Thanks.